# VueJS - also submit line breaks at the beginning and end of a textarea

Tags: php, vue.js, textarea, submit, axios

I am using axios in a VueJS component to submit a textarea bound with v-model.

```
<textarea placeholder="Insert text here" v-model="body"></textarea>
```

This is working fine (without the dot):

> Sample text
>
> .
>
> After the line break

And the output after submitting it to my PHP-Controller  is:

> Sample text/n
>
> /n
>
> After the line break

With line breaks at beginning and end:

> .
>
> Sample text
>
> .
>
> After the line break
>
> .

Above example should have the following output:

> /n
>
> Sample text/n
>
> /n
>
> After the line break/n
>
> /n

But the line breaks at the beginning and end are ignored.

Is there a way to submit those too?

Comment: why not just add them? `$var = "\n" . $var . "\n";`

Comment: @delboy1978uk Because it should depend on the textarea input. The line breaks should only be applied if a user is adding line breaks at the beginning and/or end.

Comment: Check you don't have a whitespace  trim filter in your form class

Comment: Strange, apparently you dont https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/forms.html#trim

Comment: _“But the line breaks at the beginning and end are ignored.”_ - how _exactly_ did you verify that?

Comment: @delboy1978uk Nope there is no trim. I guess then the line breaks in between would also not appear.

Comment: trim only works on the start and end of a string

Comment: @misorude After submitting to my controller I `echo` out the submitted string. The result is what I have in the second blockquote even with the line breaks at beginning and end.

Comment: @delboy1978uk Ah, right. Thank you but still I do not use any `trim` function.

Comment: _“The result is what I have in the second blockquote”_ - and have you actually checked the generated HTML _source code_, or did you just look at how your browser _interpreted_ it?

Comment: @misorude I am not 100% sure what you mean by _"generated HTML source code"_. Should I check the value of HTML `<textarea></textarea>`? It is empty because the value is bound to `v-model`.

Comment: I am referring to this: _“After submitting to my controller I echo out the submitted string.”_ - that meant server-side, in PHP, yes? So check what the actual output of that was, on the source code level, not _after_ your browser has interpreted this as HTML.

Comment: @misorude Hm, I think that took me a step further. I did a `console.log(this.body)` before the submission and there I do have the correct line breaks. The question is why they are trimmed after sending it to my server.

Comment: @misorude Yes. I proofed that with the `console.log` of my `v-model` variable.
I also did the `echo` server side and there the line breaks were gone which leaded me to the solution. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution. I actually should have mentioned that I am using the **Laravel framework** which is trimming all incoming request strings automatically with a middleware.

After commenting out the

```
\App\Http\Middleware\TrimStrings::class
```

in `Kernel.php` I disabled the auto-trim. Now I have my desired line breaks.